# C system("echo $HOME"); want what $HOME points to

Tags: c#, system

Programming in C: want to use special characters in system command.
system("echo $HOME");
want $HOME system variable not the literal $HOME.
Thanks,
Keith

Comment: c and c# are not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // for getenv()
int main()
{
    char *home;
    home = getenv("HOME");
    printf("Value is = %s\n", home);
}
```